# Prove the values occur the same number of times

Tags: number-theory

> Is there an easy way to tell that $(1-5kx) \pmod{25}$ takes on only the values $1,6,11,16,21$ the same number of times if $0 \leq k \leq 4$ and $1 \leq x \leq 4$?

We could always just list the values to confirm this, but I was wondering if there was an easy way of telling that those values must occur the same number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Since $kx$ is multiplied by $5$ and we're taking the residue modulo $25$, we're interested in the residue of $kx$ modulo $5$. Since $5$ is a prime, multiplying by $1\le x\le4$ merely permutes the five values of $k$ modulo $5$. Thus $kx\bmod5$ takes on each of the five values $4$ times, and the corresponding residues of $1-5kx$ modulo $25$ are $1+5n$ with $0\le n\le4$.